# imprimir uma lista retornada do servlet em um jsp

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet

Bom dia, caras estou me matando para fazer o meu jsp retormar uma lista que vem do BD, estou pegando as informações do banco e consigo lançar do servlet para o jsp porém não de forma ordenada e dinâmica, acaba puxando todos os itens na mesma linha, não em forma de tabela.`<tr> <td><% out.print(obj.getSitema());%></td></tr>`
ele traz todos na mesma linha e não um abaixo do outro.

poderiam me ajudar

```
> JSP


   <body>

        <% incidenteDao inci = new incidenteDao();
            Sistema sist = new Sistema();
            for (Iterator it = inci.listaIncidentes().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                obj = (Sistema) it.next(); %>  
    <tr> 
        <td><% out.print(obj.getSitema());%></td>
    <tr>


<c:forEach var="lista" items="${lista}">
    <tr>
      <td><% out.print(obj.getSitema());%></td>

    </tr>
  </c:forEach>


> SERVLET

      incidenteDao inciDao = new incidenteDao();
            Sistema sistema = null;
            List<Sistema> listas = inciDao.listaIncidentes();

            request.setAttribute("listas", listas);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("teste.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda cara, consegui um jeito de resolver

```
  <table class="table" id="tbInci">
                        <tr> 
                            <th>Ocorrência</th>
                            <th>Sistema</th>
                            <th>Horario abertura </th>
                            <th>numero do chamado</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        </tr>
                        <% incidenteDao inciDao = new incidenteDao();

                            List<Sistema> incidentes = inciDao.listaIncidentes();

                            for (Sistema s : incidentes) {

                        %>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <%=s.getOcorrencia()%></td>   
                            <td> <%=s.getSitema()%></td>
                            <td> <%=s.getAbertura()%></td>
                            <td><%=s.getChamado()%></td>
                            <td> <%=s.getStatus()%><br></td>
                        </tr>
                        <%}%>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa recuperar as propriedades do seu objeto **Sistema** de maneira individual para cada coluna. No seu exemplo seria algo do tipo:

```
<c:forEach var="obj" items="${lista}">
  <tr>
     <td>${obj.propriedade1}</td>
     <td>${obj.propriedade2}</td>
     <td>${obj.propriedade3}</td>
     <td>${obj.propriedade4}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

O valor definido em **var** possui um objeto inserido na sua **lista**. Para cada objeto, você precisará recuperar o valor de cada propriedade.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha entendo errado mas se fiz certo.  Infelizmente não funcionou colega  esse é o retorno do meu banco >>
 {  web sistemas sistemas sistemas }, pois se eu repetir o processo vai repetir a mesma linha, com todo o conteúdo da list, não um por um  por algum motivo não esta sendo possivel puxar tambem o indice

Comment: tentei tambem com isto porem não lista nada na tela do jsp

   <c:forEach var="listas" items="${listas}"> 

        <tr>
            <td>${listas.sistema}</td>

        </tr>

    </c:forEach>

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, veja se ajuda.